# Create a script to run with a specific checkbox

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Please help me with the script I want to run when I check a specific checkbox in Google Sheets. It works for me when I put it with a button but it doesn't work on tablets so I want to make it with a checkbox.

```
function sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment() {
let blob =     getFileAsBlob("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FuTHRBQ0JRmo35kcrFBIhzjRXGTea3Xznek1lKE6xT0/export?format=pdf&scale=3");
blob.setName("ΘΕΛΩ ΕΧΩ ΕΘ.ΑΝΤΙΣΤΑΣΕΩΣ");
  var message = {
    to: "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
    subject: "ΘΕΛΩ ΕΧΩ ΕΘ.ΑΝΤΙΣΤΑΣΕΩΣ",
    body: "Χαίρεται,\n\nΠαρακαλώ βρείτε συννημένη τη σημερινή     παραγγελία.\n\nΕυχαριστώ,\nΠαραγγελίες",
        name: "ΕΘ.ΑΝΤΙΣΤΑΣΕΩΣ",
    attachments: [blob.setName("ΘΕΛΩ ΕΧΩ ΕΘ.ΑΝΤΙΣΤΑΣΕΩΣ")]
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

**and the other is related to the script above**

```
function getFileAsBlob(exportUrl) {
 let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
     muteHttpExceptions: true,
     headers: {
       Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
     },
   });
 return response.getBlob();
}
```

Thank you very much.

It works for me when I put it with a button but it doesn't work on tablets so I want to make it with a checkbox.

Comment: FYI: Java != JavaScript (they are totally seperate languages that have similar names for silly historical reasons). I have updated the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an installable trigger

```
function onMyEdit(e) {//make it an installable trigger
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment();
  }
}
```

- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, but I would like the one you sent me as soon as I select the checkbox and send the email automatically to clear, not to be selected. Do you know how this can be done???

Comment: I do not understand your comment.  What is `the one I sent you`?  Everything starts on the checking of the checkbox.

Comment: What I would like is the script you sent me to clear the checkbox automatically after I select it.
Thank you very much in advance and sorry if I didn't explain it properly.

Answer (score 0):

### Running a Script When Checkbox Is Ticked

#### First Method

There are two ways to run a script when a checkbox is ticked. First, you can use the google sheets built-in `if` condition. To do this, paste the following into any empty cell. **Make sure to replace `A1` with the location of your checkbox.**

```
=IF(A1,sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment(),"")
```

This will run your function when the checkbox is ticked, and nothing when the checkbox is unticked.

#### Second Method

Paste the following code into the Google Apps Script where you have your functions, found on `Extensions > Apps Script`

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var range = event.range;
  if (range.getA1Notation() == 'A1') {
    var value = range.getValue();
    if (typeof value === 'boolean' && value == true) {
      range.setNote("Box ticked on " + new Date())
      sendExportedSheetAsPDFAttachment();
    }
  }
}
```

**Once again, replace `A1` with the location of your checkbox.**